# Using regex, extract values from a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Need to extract values from a string using regex(for perf reasons). 
Cases might be as follows:

1. RED,100
2. RED,"100"
3. RED,"100,"
4. RED,"100\"ABC\"200"

The resulting separated [label, value] array should be:

1. ['RED','100']
2. ['RED','100']
3. ['RED','100,']
4. ['RED','100"ABC"200']

I looked into solutions and a popular library even, just splits the entire string to get the values,
e.g. 'RED,100'.split(/,/) might just do the thing.

But I was trying to make a regex with comma, which splits only if that comma is not enclosed within a quotes type value.

This isnt a standard CSV behaviour might be. But its very easy for end-user to enter values.
enter label,value. Do whatever inside value, if thats surrounded by quotes. If you wanna contain quotes, use a backslash.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes take the case 3. If we split by comma, it will break in 3 piece right? which we dont want

Comment: can comma  be in the fisrt part (RED) ?

Comment: Yes the same is true for first part i.e. label as well.

Comment: From user`s point its simple entry. the format is label,value

But if you want to enter comma(,) or quotes(") inside either label/value, we wont be splitting on that,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex that takes care of escaped quotes in string:

```
/"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|[^,"]+/g
```

**RegEx Explanation:**

- `"`: Match a literal opening quote
- `[^"\\]*`: Match 0 or more of any character that is not `\` and not a quote
- `(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*`:  Followed by escaped character and another non-quote, non-`\`. Match 0 or more of this combination to get through all escaped characters
- `"`: Match closing quote
- `|`: OR (alternation)
- `[^,"]+`: Match 1+ of non-quote, non-comma string

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qVQc1F/1)

```js
const regex = /"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|[^,"]+/g;

const arr = [`RED,100`, `RED,"100"`, `RED,"100,"`,
`RED,"100\\"ABC\\"200"`];
let m;

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var str = arr[i];
  var result = [];
  while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    result.push(m[0]);
  }
  console.log("Input:", str, ":: Result =>", result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. This is incredible. Took almost 10mins to go by it. Thanks again. You just inspired me about the powers of regex.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and take only the groups.

```js
var array = ['RED,100', 'RED,"100"', 'RED,"100,"', 'RED,"100\"ABC\"200"'];

console.log(array.map(s => s.match(/^([^,]+),(.*)$/).slice(1)))
```